# Is there an infallible method to redirect depending on browser and browser version?

Tags: php, redirect, http-redirect

I would like to redirect users to another webpage depending on the browser and browser version he/she is using.

I know this can be done with simple javascript code and also with PHP with the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` parameter. However, both methods can be evaded either deactivating javascript or changing the user_agent manually.

My question is: Is there  way to redirect that gives no chances to the client to evade it?

Comment: Conditional comments with a HTML meta refresh could work for IE sites less than version 10 at least. But it's still HTML so you could mess with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "depending on the browser and browser version" ? As in, "if IE, then go to IE.html, if CHROME, then go to CHROME.html" etc? if so: how do you know this can be reliably done? because you can't. The user controls what information he/she sends to you. You can go a long way, but not infallible

Comment: The better question would be, why do you need to do this? Chances are pretty good that your assumptions are incorrect, this isn't something you should ever need to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to check the user-agent and issue a [301 moved permanently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) redirect header with no meaningful content in the body besides a "this page has moved" message. The browser will either obey it, or render an empty document. The important thing is to recognize that the user-agent string is *optional*, and you absolutely shouldn't make it a required part of using your site.

Note that your attitude is antithetical to the entire nature of the Internet. There is no way to *force* the user's browser to do *anything*, nor should there be, ever. All behaviour is entirely optional, and the user is free to fetch your website or parts of your website, and programatically do *whatever they want* with the data you send them.

Comment: As far as I understood OP does not want to redirect every user. Actually, question is: Is there a way that will tell me which browser user uses and I can be sure?

Comment: Thank you for reading and re-reading. Im still not sure though if the esence of my message was 100% understood. The only thing Im looking for here is to redirect users when they are using IE lower than 7, I do not see any antithetical attitude on that. However, with yours and the other comments I am clear now that there is not INFALLIBLE method to do this.

Comment: *Ordering* the browser to do something is antithetical to the nature of the Internet. This is no *infallible* way to make anybody do anything; the Internet is about *requests*, not *commands*.

Answer (score 1):

You only communicate with the client via text strings over the wire. If the client does not want to tell you his real user agent, there really isn't much you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:no

This would make life a lot easier, but browsers vind privacy of users more important then the desires of website builders.

The best you can do is make your website as downwards compatible as possible.

The only culprit I usually encounter are the various versions of IE from 6 - 10 which all require different stylesheet rules.

I would simply use in the head

```
<head>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie6.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie9.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 10]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ie10.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I will do something very similar. Thank you.